# Convex set euclidean ball proof

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I was studying some notes on convex optimization and came across this formula

Euclidean ball with center $x_c$ and radius r:

$${\{x_c + ru ∣ ∥u∥_2 \leq 1}\}$$

How do i even go about proving that this is a convex set. I am extremely new to this and i am not asking for answers. But i just need to even know how to start proving.

I am not even sure what does this mean

https://www.ics.uci.edu/~xhx/courses/CS206/convex_sets.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify the definition (see page 1 of the linked pdf): let $x_1, x_2\in B:={\{x_c + ru ∣ \|u\|_2 \leq 1}\}$ that is, 
$$x_1=x_c+ru_1\quad \text{and}\quad x_2=x_c+ru_2$$
with $\|u_1\|_2 \leq 1$ and $\|u_2\|_2 \leq 1$,
 and let $\theta\in[0,1]$, then show that 
$$\theta x_1+(1-\theta)x_2=\theta(x_c+ru_1)+(1-\theta)(x_c+ru_2)\\=x_c+r(\theta u_1+(1-\theta)u_2)$$
belongs to $B$, that is $\|\theta u_1+(1-\theta)u_2\|_2\leq 1$.

Comment: am i right to say that your last line is correct because of the nature of the original definition that the thetas sum up to 1?

Comment: @aceminer no, the last line is still a challenge. You asked 'how to start proving' and this answer shows you how to start.

Comment: @aceminer No, in order to prove the last line you should use the definition of $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks! it helped me solve my question

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of convex, it is straightforward to show that if $C$ is convex then
the translate $\{ x+c | c \in C\}$ is convex.

Using the definition of convex, it is straightforward to show that if $C$ is convex then
the scaled set $\{ rc | c \in C\}$ is convex.

Since the norm $\| \cdot \|$ is a convex function, it is straightforward to show, from the
definition, that the set $\{x | \|x\| \le  1\}$ is convex.